# ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1 when trying to install ciso8601

Tags: python, installation

Im a rookie to start programming. It would so much appreciated if you can help me on this.
Im using Windows 8 64bits and Python 3.7.  thank you guys so much!!

The error popped up when I tried to install ciso8601 in Pycharm.
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:

```
Collecting ciso8601
Using cached ciso8601-2.1.3.tar.gz (15 kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: ciso8601
Building wheel for ciso8601 (setup.py): started
Building wheel for ciso8601 (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
Running setup.py clean for ciso8601
Failed to build ciso8601
Installing collected packages: ciso8601
Running setup.py install for ciso8601: started
Running setup.py install for ciso8601: finished with status 'error'

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
command: 
Complete output (14 lines):
running bdist_wheel
running build
running build_py
package init file 'ciso8601\__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
creating build
creating build\lib.win32-3.7
creating build\lib.win32-3.7\ciso8601
copying ciso8601\__init__.pyi -> build\lib.win32-3.7\ciso8601
copying ciso8601\py.typed -> build\lib.win32-3.7\ciso8601
warning: build_py: byte-compiling is disabled, skipping.

running build_ext
building 'ciso8601' extension
error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build 
Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/

Collecting ciso8601
Using cached ciso8601-2.1.3.tar.gz (15 kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: ciso8601
Building wheel for ciso8601 (setup.py): started
Building wheel for ciso8601 (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
Running setup.py clean for ciso8601
Failed to build ciso8601
Installing collected packages: ciso8601
Running setup.py install for ciso8601: started
Running setup.py install for ciso8601: finished with status 'error'

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
command: 
Complete output (14 lines):
running bdist_wheel
running build 
running build_py
package init file 'ciso8601\__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
creating build
creating build\lib.win32-3.7
creating build\lib.win32-3.7\ciso8601
copying ciso8601\__init__.pyi -> build\lib.win32-3.7\ciso8601
copying ciso8601\py.typed -> build\lib.win32-3.7\ciso8601
warning: build_py: byte-compiling is disabled, skipping.

running build_ext
building 'ciso8601' extension
error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build 
Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to Install with docker. Beacuse ciso8601 is a Python extension written in C. [Source: GitHub](https://github.com/closeio/ciso8601/issues/98)